# Percentage Reported By PHPUnit: What Does it Mean?

Tags: phpunit

I'm working on my first project in which I'm utilizing PHPUnit for unit testing. Things have been moving along nicely; however, I've started getting the following output with recent tests:

```
................................................................. 65 / 76 ( 85%)
...........

Time: 1 second, Memory: 30.50Mb

OK (76 tests, 404 assertions)
```

I cannot find any information about what the "65 / 76 ( 85%)" means.

Does anyone know how to interpret this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Percentage of tests executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582866/percentage-of-tests-executed)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means the amount of tests that have been run so far (test methods actually, or to be even more precise: test method calls, because each test method can be called several times).

```
65 / 76 ( 85%)
```

65 tests of 76 have already run (which is 85% overall)

And as long as you see dots for each of them - all of them passed

Comment: Oh geez...so that it just telling me how many have run at that point? Ha...awesome. I thought I started doing something wrong, but it appears that I get that output because I passed a particular threshold. Thanks!

Comment: @Sardine: yep, it is that simple

Comment: Awesome! In precisely 10 minutes, I will accept this answer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This thing made me lose almost an hour for nothing. I thought I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't understand it until I kept writing more tests, here's a sample of what you see as the number of tests grow:

```
...............................................................  63 / 152 ( 41%)
...............................................................  126 / 152 ( 82%)
..........................
```

...it's just a progress indicator of the number of tests that have been run. But as you can see, it still gets to the end.