# Percentage of tests executed

Tags: php, phpunit

I am running my phpunit tests in a project and I get this response:

```
................................. 65 / 81 ( 80%)
................

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 9.25Mb

OK (81 tests, 190 assertions)
```

What does that mean? I had never seen it in other projects I regularly work on. Does that percentage (80%) represent the number of tests that are actually executed? Why just the 80%? I don't get it.

Comment: *"I had never seen it in other projects I regularly work on"* - Did those projects have fewer than 65 tests?

Answer (score 6):

All it's doing is showing a percentage because there are so many tests it needs to start a new line for more space to enter '.' characters.  So before it moves to the next line it tells you how many are completed on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Because `(65 / 81) * 100 = 80%`

Yes, it's the percentage of completed tests

Comment: [`(65 / 81) * 100 = 80.2469136`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=(65+%2F+81)+*+100) actually :P

Answer (score 0):

It is just giving you an indication as to the progress.